# Design pattern for microservice that makes rest calls to API that frequently times out

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, design-patterns, microservices

I have just inherited a project to redesign a Spring Boot microservice that

1. parses a large csv file and
2. for each line - executes a rest client getForObject request on a remote API
3. the object is then saved to a file in S3

We have no control over the remote API, and are limited to a single GET request per object.  The csv files can be tens of thousands of lines in length, and the remote API frequently times out when under heavy load - so processing these files can take a long time and also frequently throws exceptions due to request timeouts.  Resilience4j is already part of the code - but has not been very helpful as their API seems very brittle.

Wondering if anyone has dealt w this type of problem, or could suggest any design patterns, caching or batching solutions, that would allow us to

1. process large csv batches in an efficient manner despite lack of
   batching capabilities in the remote API - possibly some type of
   caching solution
2. would allow us to save off requests incomplete/error state for error
   reporting and retry purposes

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "brittle API" e: Resilience4j. But: it's unclear what kind of information you're looking for here (and it's likely not a great SO question). "Batching" seems not-helpful unless there's some domain-specific reason it makes sense. Other than simple retry logic and "ok"/"not-ok" buckets what is left?

Comment: Do the CSVs include duplicate lines? Could you reduce the network load by deduping?

Comment: @DaveNewton yeah sorry I didn't know how best to describe what I'm asking for.  This is kind of a strange problem.

Comment: @jaco0646. there are no duplicate lines

Comment: It's not at all strange--it's a common scenario. It's just not clear what you think the problem is.

Comment: @DaveNewton i guess as it is currently designed (not by me) - each of the individual rest requests per csv line can time out - which doesn't invalidate the entire csvs file processing - but there are a couple problems.  we currently have no way of saving off indiidual requests that errored out for retry later, and the entire process currently takes quite a long time since we are talking about making many thousands of rest requests per csv file, wondering if there was a way to make it more efficient.

Comment: If you are limited by something outside of your control I don't see how. You *might* be able to parallelize the requests. You can certainly implement retry logic and tracking of which requests succeed and fail (both of which seem like they should already be in place, as they're problems intrinsic to what's being done).

Comment: You should have a look at frameworks like Spring Batch to implement batch processing properly.